# Place combobox to bootstrap datatable header search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, combobox, bootstrap-4

I want to place combobox to search field in bootstrap datatable header.
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
This link make combobox to tfoot.
But I want to place it in search field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

This is javascript code that is using in this example.
also I can change $(column.footer()).empty() to $(column.header())
But it is showing like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rc63.jpg.

As you can see in this image, the combobox placed in header but I want to place it below "Name" means replace with Search Name input field.
Please help me!!!!!
Thank you for read my question.

Comment: Well, is this impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.
In code I change

```
.appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
```

to

```
.appendTo(column.context[0].nTHead.childNodes[3].childNodes[1])
```

This indicates that cell that I want.